Some calculation in Schwartz's Quantum field theory eq. (16.39)
In Schwartz's Quantum field theory and the standard model, p.307 he derives a formula:
$$ \Pi_2^{\mu \nu} = \frac{-2 e^2}{(4 \pi )^{d/2}}(p^2g^{\mu\nu}-p^{\mu}p^{\nu})\Gamma(2- \frac{d}{2}) \mu^{4-d} \times  \int_{0}^{1} dx\ x(2x-1)(\frac{1}{m^2-p^{2}x(1-x)})^{2- \frac{d}{2}}  \tag{16.38} $$
(What is definition of the $\Pi_2^{\mu \nu}$ ? What we call such object?) Then he claims that expanding $d= 4-\epsilon$ we get, in the $\epsilon \to 0$ limit,
$$ \Pi_2^{\mu \nu} = -\frac{e^2}{8 \pi^2}(p^2g^{\mu\nu}-p^{\mu}p^{\nu})\int_{0}^{1} dx\ x(2x-1) [ \frac{2 }{\epsilon} + \ln(\frac{4 \pi e^{-\gamma_E}\mu^2}{m^2-p^2 x(1-x)}) + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon)]. \tag{16.39} $$
Why this calculation is true? What is meaning of "expanding $d=4-\epsilon$" ? What is the $\gamma_E$ in the numerator in $\ln$ ? I think we may use the definition/properties of the Gamma function and taylor expansion and I still don't know how to calculate rigorously to reach to the $(16.39)$. Can anyone help?

I can only help you with the second question. The $d=4-\epsilon$ is a trick to calculate certain integrals that diverge for $d=4$. The idea is to calculate the integral for arbitrary dimension $d$. The number of dimensions is of course an integer, but we can analytically expand the answer for $d\in\mathbb R$. Finally you take the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ to get the answer in 4 dimensions.

$\Pi_2^{\mu\nu}$ is the vacuum polarization tensor

You are reading a chapter on vacuum polarization (!) and are required to master Appendix B.3. The Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma_E$ is defined on p 827. I strongly recommend you delete/reformulate your question in light of this due diligence. You cannot ask the community to read a clear text together with you.

@Cosmas Zachos : O.K. Thank you. The world of quantum field theory is occasionally difficult for me :~(


What is definition of  $\Pi_2^{\mu \nu}$? What do we call such an object?

It is defined in (16.24), the vacuum polarization tensor, after which the chapter is named.

What is $\gamma_E$?

As your text requires you to master first, in Appendix B.3, it is the Euler-Mascheroni constant in the crucial formula
$$
\Gamma (\epsilon/2) = {2\over \epsilon}- \gamma_E + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon) . \tag{B.31 } $$
The mechanics of dimensional regularization is explained there: the big picture.
After  elementary algebra, you are asked to look at the small $\epsilon$ limit of the integrand factor
$$
\Gamma (\epsilon/2) \left ( \frac{4\pi \mu^2}{m^2-p^{2}x(1-x)}\right ) ^{\epsilon/2}\\ =\left({2\over \epsilon}- \gamma_E + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon) \right) e^{{\epsilon\over 2}\ln (4\pi \mu^2/(m^2-p^{2}x(1-x))}\\ 
= \left({2\over \epsilon}- \gamma_E + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon) \right) \left( 1+{\epsilon\over 2} \ln (4\pi \mu^2/(m^2-p^{2}x(1-x))  + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2) \right)\\
= {2\over \epsilon} +\ln \left (\frac{4\pi \mu^2 e^{-\gamma_E}}{m^2-p^{2}x(1-x)} \right) +\mathcal{O}(\epsilon) .
$$

O.K. Thank you. I learned a lot :)
